# Use Storybook with auto-generated argTypes for components in external TypeScript library

Tags: webpack, storybook, rollupjs, lerna

We built a **Design System library** in TypeScript with the components, and we created the Storybook stories and all **in another project** that consume the transpiled component library, as a package.

Currently, in each story for each component we have to define all the [`argTypes`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes) manually.

1. I expected the Storybook to understand the `argType` (the component props) **from the TypeScript types**.
2. Also, I expected Storybook to **fetch the JSDoc from the component library**, since the IDE know to do that.

I tried to *infer additional props* as described in [Storybook TypeScript documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/typescript#overriding-the-configuration-to-infer-additional-props):

```js
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: [],
  typescript: {
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      compilerOptions: {
        allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false,
        esModuleInterop: false,
      },
    }
  }
};
```

I also tried to use `ComponentMeta<MyProps>` (and `Meta<MyProps>`) and `ComponentStory<MyProps>` (and `Story<MyProps>`) as the story types, but it didn't help.